# do div also take space for itself?

Tags: html, for-loop, space

and i had made a division using `div` tag 
under that three different `div` tags

i.e.

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="div1">
     </div>
     <div id="div2">
     </div>
     <div id="div3">
     </div>
</div>
```

I had made a css for it

```
#content
{
   width:960px;
}
#div1,div2,div3
{
 width:318px;
 border-radius:10px;
 border:1px solid;
 float:left;
 margin-left:2px
}
```

now my problem is that my `div` does not arranged in a single row ,
if I change width to `315px` of `div1`, `div2`, `div3` then it will appear on a single line

i.e one after another.

can anybody please tell me why it's so?

Comment: increase the width of your main div

Comment: but why my div dont have to take the space

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing

```
#div1,div2,div3
```

to

```
#div1,#div2,#div3
```

?
They appear on a single row to me.

Comment: yaah i had placed seperately here for saving time i write like this.

Comment: when i made it to 315 it is ok came in single row

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about border(+2px), margin and padding. Bordered div is 320px wide, so in addition to margin or padding it overflows the container.